# Four letter puzzles on US states

Tags: word, geography, knowledge

Here are four questions on the letters in the names of US states and US state capitals:

1. What is the only US state that has no letter in common with it's capital city?
2. What is the only US state capital that doesn't contain a letter from the word MACKEREL?
3. What is the only US state that doesn't contain a letter from the word MACKEREL?
4. What is the only US state that doesn't contain a letter from the word COMMUNIST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to look at a list of states and capitals to figure this out.

> 1. South Dakota
>  2. Boston
>  3. Ohio
>  4. Delaware